# zombie xib file

Tags: xcode

My app had a xib file, but I noticed that when the app was running, it was actually accessing the xib from some other app on my development system. I have been trying to locate that other xib file, but without any luck, so I deleted the only xib file from this app, but the app still compiles and runs on my ipad with that zombie button. I am using ARC, I think, btw.

What can I do?

Comment: First, delete the app from your device (or the simulator if that's where your testing it).  Next, in Xcode, hold the Option key down and choose Product > Clean Build Folder (then click Clean).  Then build and run the app again.  Does it still build successfully and use the “zombie” xib?

Comment: Yes, it's still there. Wait. I may not have deleted it, just stopped it. Let me delete it. That did it. Thanks.